# Golang import; go get mywebsite.com/mylibrary/function

Tags: go, import, get

Some of my code written for work is not suitable for public. So, I like to run within company's server. What would be the easiest way to retreat the library using "go get" from a private server.
<strike>What would be easiest way to have library on Apache website?</strike>

Below are what I'd like to do.

**Get my code**

> go get mysite.com/libraries/mylib1

**Source**

```
package main
import(
    "mysite.com/libraries/mylib1"
)

func main() {
    mylib1.Print()
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Just to clarify, Apache is the *webserver*. You store your code on a *server*, and access it with the webserver (namely Apache).

Comment: Yes. The question is how to retreat the code from the private web address.

Comment: By the way, I wasn't retreat using "go get" from the company's website. It seems like it requires something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem what we did was just spin up our own GitLab server to hold all of the libraries/code.

Comment: I guess this maybe the only way.. Thank you Kyle

Answer (score 0):

just have the code in `$GOPATH/src/mysite.com/project`

easiest would be an own git server.

Comment: Thanks, however, the code needs to be in the server which doesn't have mounted. So, this will not work. I need something that uses a web server.

Comment: @Gon: you just do what go get does, and clone the repo into the correct import path. Other than as a convenience for `go get`, the actual import path is meaningless. You don't need a webserver at all.

Comment: Oh new tip! Thanks @JumB.